# Controlling the distribution of tests with py.test xdist

Tags: python, testing, nose, pytest

I have several thousand tests that I want to run in parallel. The tests are all compiled binaries that give a return code of 0 or non-zero (on failure). Some unknown subsets of them try to use the same resources (files, ports, etc). Each test assumes that it is running independently and just reports a failure if a resources isn't available.

I'm using Python to launch each test using the subprocess module, and that works great serially. I looked into Nose for parallelizing, but I need to autogenerate the tests (to wrap each of the 1000+ binaries into Python class that uses subprocess) and Nose's multiprocessing module doesn't support parallelizing autogenerated tests.

I ultimately settled on PyTest because it can run autogenerated tests on remote hosts over SSH with the xdist plugin.

However, as far as I can tell, it doesn't look like xdist supports any kind of control of how the tests get distributed. I want to give it a pool of N machines, and have one test run per machine.

Is what I want possible with PyTest/xdist? If not, is there a tool out there that can do what I'm looking for?

Comment: were you able to find a way to do this with py.test xdist?
 "I want to give it a pool of N machines, and have one test run per machine"

If not with xdist, do you have any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would help. But if you know ahead of time how you want to divide up your tests, instead of having pytest distribute your tests, you could use your continuous integration server to call a different run of pytest for each different machine. Using -k or -m to select a subset of tests, or simply specifying different test dir paths, you could control which tests are run together.